# How to convert this optimization problem into a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

How to convert this problem:
[image]

into this problem:

[image]

I am not getting the angle to attack this problem from. How to remove the denominator? Doesn't it also depend on `x`, thereby not being a constant, meaning we can' ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: let $t=\frac{1}{c^{T}x+d}$ and $y=tx$.

Comment: Thanks. I got it with a bit of manipulation. But I would be grateful if you let me know how you come up with these substitutions? Is there a trick or formula to come up with such variable transformations? Thanks again.

Comment: That's a good question. Obviously I'm not the one who came up with them, they are part of a set of classical tricks you learn when studying operations research. The people who come up with such tricks are geniuses, they have above average inspiration I guess!